# Match same regex multiple times?

Tags: ruby

```
foo = '1234567890'
foo.sub(/(.{3})(.{3})/, '\1-\2-')
 #=> "123-456-7890"
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
foo.gsub(/(.{3})\2/, '\1-\2-')
```

Notice semi-pseudo code `\2` is to signify `match (this) pattern twice` this pattern being `(.{3})` so that I can get the same result of `#=> "123-456-7890"`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`{2}` is "match this pattern twice" (which I suppose you already should know, since you're using a very similar `{3}` "match this pattern thrice" modifier). So, not 100% sure what you're asking, really. :)

However, you can't have different groups for different matches of the same pattern; thus, your replacement would not work.

You can do something kind of similar using `String#scan` if you really want the repeated pattern thing (you get them in an array).

Comment: No string#scan just adds unnecessary complication. Just wanted to streamline the regex. I feel like I've seen it done in other languages..